# What is xl and xu in a chi square distribution

Tags: upper-lower-bounds, confidence-interval, chi-squared

I have an Excel worksheet from someone smarter than me and I am trying to understand what mathematic process is being calculated.

Cell **F9** contains
$$ =\mathop{CHISQ.INV.RT}(F8, 2)$$ where **F8**$=0.0063%$ (this is labeled "Fraction defective").

I have gathered that this comes from $C_p/C_{pk}$ of $1.33\dot{3}$ which is a 4-sigma process and which is 63.342 defective parts per million. This much makes sense knowing the context of this excel sheet.

**Where I am stuck** is the formulas in cells **F11**, **F12**, and **F13** (labeled *xl*, *xu*, and *xu$-$xl*). I assume this is x lower, x upper and the difference between them and think that this is some sort of confidence interval. However, I cannot find a formula online anywhere that matches the formula they used.

In F11 they have: **F4**-**F5**$\ast SQRT($**F9**$)+0.00001$ where **F4** is the average and **F5** is the standard deviation. Similarly, **F12** is: **F4**+**F5**$\ast SQRT($**F9**$)-0.00001$.

What are these formulae calculating? **F13** simply is: **F12**$-$**F11**

Comment: F5 is multiplied by the sqrt in both equations... I don't know why the multiplication symbol didn't display...

Comment: Note that the [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) has standard deviation equal to the square root of its mean.  This means that if you are counting independent occurrences of some phenomenon in a fixed time period (like `F9` might be?), it's reasonable to assume the error in your count is roughly the square root of your count (`SQRT(F9)`).  But I don't know enough about your situation to understand why that should be scaled by `F5`, nor what the `0.00001`s are doing.

Comment: I am not very proficient at statistical math. But as I stated in my post, F9 is a chi squared calculation. In Excel the formula for chi squared is "=CHISQ.INV.RT(F8,2)" where the "F8=0.0063" (this is the probability) and the "2" means 2 degrees of freedom. Chi squared does not return a count right? Unless I am completely misunderstanding what chi squared is (which is possible). I have found that there is a table that exists (old school where you can look up chi squared) and it matches the result from the excel equation in cell F9 which is 19.34475.

Comment: Also, I have found some tables of confidence intervals and such that have 99.999%. I don't know if that is where the 0.00001 comes from or not (it may just be a coincidence). My other thought was that a zero value may result in an error and they were simply making sure the value is never zero by adding 0.00001. Chi square distribution is represented by X^2 & as I understand, if i take the square root of that. Then I get simply X. Which as I understand is called a chi distribution. They are multiplying the chi distribution by the standard deviation & adding & subtracting this from the mean.

Comment: Equations describe relationships between quantities, but you're asking us to interpret equations without giving us any context into the quantities those equations should describe.  Please add to the question what properties in the real world you measure to input into this spreadsheet.  (cont.)

Comment: It sounds like maybe you're doing product testing on an assembly line.  Could any of the quantities on the sheet represent "the number of defective products" (which would be a count)?  If this were a classic [$\chi^2$ test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test), then there would be a $\chi^2$-distributed random variable that represents a count of observed events.  (cont.)

Comment: More generally, thinking about something being "a $\chi^2$ calculation" is too simplistic: there are _many_ different questions you can ask about random variables with the $\chi^2$ distribution.  In this case, `F9` is _inverting the CDF_: if $X$ is assumed to have $\chi^2$ distribution, then it takes on values larger than `F9` with probability at most `F8`.